# Insert into multiple tables SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

How can one insert a row into one table and use the id generated from that row into another row so that there can be a transaction around the whole thing?
The problem I'm having is that there is massive db latency because I have 100k records, but I can only transact 1-100 at a time.

```
INSERT INTO foo;
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT INTO foo;
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
INSERT into bar(foo_id) VALUES (last_foo_id)
```

Comment: just how many `bar` records are you inserting? start a transaction, insert into foo, do the multiple bar inserts, then commit. start a new transactions, do another `foo`, then the `bar`s, commit, etc...

Comment: Yes.  Already doing that.  Still bottlenecked.  I'm doing 99% inserts into bar.

Comment: What is your client SQLite library and/or language? Is it Perl, Python, SQLite C/API, or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

After inserting the `foo` record, read its ID with [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) (or whatever your database wrapper uses for that), and use that value in all the following `bar` insert statements:

```py
db.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
db.execute("INSERT INTO foo ...")
foo_id = db.last_insert_rowid
db.execute("INSERT INTO bar(foo_id) VALUES (?)", [foo_id])
...
db.execute("COMMIT TRANSACTION")
```

Comment: How can I wrap that in a transaction?  That is actually the purpose of this question.

Comment: Just how you would wrap any other statements. How is this ID related with transactions?

Comment: My whole question is to avoid this method which is costing a lot of latency.  This is how I have it now.

Comment: SQLite is an *embedded* database library; you cannot save time by sending multiple commands off to a server. Each command is executed synchronously inside your process. To optimize execution time, put more commands into one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `last_insert_rowid()` function.

Comment: By the second insert into bar I'd be getting ids from the table bar not foo.